# How to switch off automatic copy to clipboard in gVim

Tags: vim, macvim

When a text is selected in (my) gVim then is copied automaticaly into the clipboard (X11 behavior). While this has been ok under X11 it starts to anoy me in Windows and Mac OS. I am sure this can be switched off somewhere. But I just can't find the propper help page. Probably using the wrong search term for Google and `:help`.

Question: Which `:set` setting do I need to toggle to make Vim behave like an OS X or Windows and copy to the clipboard only on Ctrl-C. (Mapping are already are place)

PS: Working from a company provided IE without spell check - sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have something like

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

In one of your rc files.  Remove that line.  For more information:

```
:help 'clipboard'
```

(including the quotes)

See also:

```
:help x11-selection
```

Comment: Actualy the problem was autoselect set in guioptions. But still it was nicle explained on the help page you quoted. The vim help is pretty good once you found the right page.

Comment: Yeah I often run into the problem of "I know I've seen this in here, somewhere."  E.g. I'd love to point my coworkers at the docs for the curly-braces-in-filenames that you can do, e.g. `:vimgrep /foo/ **/*.{cpp,h}`.  Alas, I saw it once, use it a lot, and cannot find it again.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question on the search for the answer to this problem..

Add this to your .gvimrc to disable autocopy in VIM

```
  " Following three lines remove the auto copy function from VIM
  set guioptions-=a
  set guioptions-=A
  set guioptions-=aA
```

Comment: To ease headaches, I'll note that I had to add this to the end of my `.gvimrc`.